# iOS - Detect and analyze music that is playing in another app?

Tags: ios, background, analyzer

I am developing an app and want to be able to detect and analyze the music that is currently playing from another app (for instance the Music app, Pandora, etc.).

My question is, is it possible to analyze music/sounds from a background app while in my app?
If so, can someone point me in the right direction of how to detect the music and actually analyze it?

I need to actually be able to analyze the music that is playing, NOT just determine if music player is active like below code does:

```
if ([[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] playbackState] == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying) ...
```

**UPDATE**

Ok, so just discovered that iOS 7 now has an "Inter-App Audio" feature that allows apps to access/manipulate audio from other apps. But can not find an example/tutorial that explains how to receive the currently playing sounds. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Inter-Application Audio can't be used that way. Not all audio on the iOS device is sent to the IAA "bus" — only audio from applications that specifically choose to transmit audio to it, usually music performance/production applications such as Garage Band.